# Using "$**" to direct file input within a Makefile

Tags: c, file-io, makefile

I am working with a large C project that has many source files. Here is a line from one of the makefiles:

```
!$(TOOLSDIRECTORY)unifdef $(UNIFDEF_ARGUMENTS) $** > $(TARGET)\$**
```

The Unifdef tool referenced by this line is open source and available here:
http://dotat.at/prog/unifdef/

In this case, the last argument to Unifdef is the group of files to process. It is my understanding that this code is using the symbol "$**" to say "every file in this folder", then piping all of the output to the TARGET directory.

My confusion is that I don't understand how Unifdef receives multiple files in one command. Does a makefile package all of the files into one file stream when it sees "$**"? I understand how Unifdef handles the input it receives, but how do multiple files turn into the single argument that Unifdef receives?

Other note: this makefile is being run on Windows in MSVS 2010.

Comment: Without seeing the target that that is under I can't say I understand what it is trying to do but it certainly doesn't look very sane to me. `$*` is the [automatic variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) which contains the stem of the implicit rule that matched. `$**` should expand to `<stem>*` which might be reasonable on the left-hand side of the redirection as a wildcard to run unifdef on a large number of files but the right-hand side of the redirection just seems odd to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows CMD prompt expands the $** into multiple individual calls to Unifdef, each one with one of the files in the directory as the argument, and pipes the output to a file of the same name in the target directory. Therefore, each call to Unifdef is only receiving one file name as its input.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this doesn't actually do what you want.

`$**` is not a single construct; it is the [special Makefile variable `$*`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables) followed immediately by the shell-glob wildcard `*`.  The line is going to be rewritten twice: first, by Make, to something like

```
!../path/to/tools/unifdef --opt1 --opt2 foo* > ../path/to/target/foo\*
```

and then, by `/bin/sh`, to something like

```
!../path/to/tools/unifdef --opt1 --opt2 foo.c foo1.c foo2.c fooquux.c \
    > ../path/to/target/foo*
```

and only then executed.

You didn't quote any of the context, so I can't be any more specific than that.  Here's why I think this can't be right, though:

1. Unless maybe you set [`.RECIPEPREFIX`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html), which is a feature I had never heard of before now, the `!` at the beginning of the command doesn't make any sense and should be causing the command to fail because there is no executable named literally `!../path/to/tools/unifdef`.
2. The backslash on the second occurrence of `$**` *does not* escape the `$*` (you would do that by writing `$$*`); it is preserved, and escapes the shell-glob star, so the output is being written to a file literally named `../path/to/target/foo*`, which is sufficiently weird that I don't think it can be what was intended.
3. If the target-directory glob weren't being escaped, there would be two more problems:

   - Glob expansion happens independently in the source and target directories, and so would (at least potentially) match unrelated sets of files.
   - The output redirection (`>`) only applies to the *very next* thing on the command line; all the other things matched by the glob in the target directory would be provided as *input* to `unifdef`.

Based on a wild-assed guess about what you're trying to do, I think you probably want something more like this:

```
# Resist the temptation to use wildcards.  It will be less grief in the long run
# to list each file explicitly.
GENERIC_SOURCES   := foo.c foo1.c foo2.c fooquux.c barblurf.c barbaz.c

UNIFDEFED_SOURCES := $(patsubst %.c,$(TARGET)/%-u.c,$(GENERIC_SOURCES))

# The indented lines below must be indented using exactly one hard tab character.
$(UNIFDEFED_SOURCES): %-u.c: %.c
        $(TOOLSDIRECTORY)unifdef $(UNIFDEF_ARGUMENTS) $< > $@T
        mv -f $@T $@
```

This does not attempt to batch invocations of `unifdef`; Make is generally *much* happier if each rule creates only one output file.

[`$(patsubst ...)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html) and the [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html) are features specifically of [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/).  I normally advocate portability, but in the case of Make, the GNU incarnation is so much more powerful than the portable feature set that it's worth carrying around as a dependency.

Comment: I appreciate your answer and would vote it up if I could, because it seems appropriate for the question as originally asked.